# Accessing postgres server with limited pg_hba.conf access

Tags: postgresql, ssh, dbeaver

I am trying to access a postgres server that has limited IP access in pg_hba.conf file.

I am trying to use dbeaver to access it.

I am - computer A

postgres server - computer C

server i can access postgres server from - computer B

In my computer I have this view.
[image]

As far as I understand I need to trick my computer into using the computer B.

So when i write postgreserver.blaah.com  into host/ip and port 5432. It will ssh to computer B and then access it from there.

So in my ssh config file i wrote this:

LocalForward 5432:postgreserver.blaah.com:5432 myuser@server.b.com

Well this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
ssh -L5432:databasehostname:5432 intermediatehostname
```

So this is running in a random shell somewhere on my screen while i am working with the database.

In DBeaver the hostname is localhost and port is 5432

and i am using Main connection tab not ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do anything in your ssh config (and which computer's ssh config was it?).  DBeaver's SSH tab is an alternative to manually setting up your own tunnel.

If you have already manually set up your own tunnel, then you would just point DBeaver to it, you wouldn't tell DBeaver that it is using a tunnel.  It doesn't need to know.

If you want DBeaver to set up the tunnel, then "computer_B" would go in the Host/IP field of the SSH tab.  "computer_C" would go in the Host field of the Main tab.